# Gdb wont open after warning

Tags: gdb, ddd-debugger

GDB will not open. I get Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-symbol-*-*-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-adobe-*" to type FontStruct

I tried several suggestions I found online and none seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You question is vague, you will receive vague answers as such. Please edit with more information.
GDB will not open? Or ddd? What flavor of linux are you running? Are you debugging locally? briefly what did you try?